# Open web page on windows CE?

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce

I need to create a batch file to open a web page from handheld computer.

I use this instruction on Windows 7:

```
start iexplore http://www.google.com
```

But it doesn't works on Windows CE. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`iesample`** (**`IESMAPLE.exe`**) ...

Answer (score 1):

With me knowing nothing about Win CE - try this.

```
start http://www.google.com
```